# Force a PostBack

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have an asp form in which on_button_click a thread a being executed following a finite number of loops. So I want after every single loop completion a postback should occur. So would you please help me out to find the way of doing post back by coding after single loop completion.

```
Thread tt = new Thread (mainProcess); 

Button1_Click() {
 tt.start();
} 

void mainprocess()
{
   while(true)
   {
      //do this 
      if(Condition)
         break;

     //do postback
   }
}
```

Comment: `Response.Write` on the same page..?

Comment: Typically a postback is the response of some sort of user interaction.  I don't know any specific use case for it, but I'm sure there's probably a better way to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: @vishal > Response is not available in this context.

Comment: Where is this loop executing?

Comment: @Andrew: Thread tt = new Thread (mainProcess);
Button1_Click() {tt.start();}
void mainprocess(){while(true){//do this //if(Condition){break;} //do postback}}

Answer (score 1):

From the moment you fire a thread on code behind, the thread did not have any control/connection with the page to make some how a postback or refresh.

You need to redesign your page some other way. One possible is to use ajax to make your call to the page and get the results when they are ready, or to make using ajax time to time call to code behind and see if the data are ready to gets them. Or make every 20 seconds a page refresh and again check if the loop has ended and get and show the data.